# Anonymous class can be replaced with lambda?

Tags: java

While i'm writing some code in intellij, it keeps popping up, says

> Anonymous class can be replaced with lambda?

So what does that mean? what is lambda expression and how Anonymous class can be replaced with lambda?

```
Play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JPanel playscreen = new JPanel();
playscreen.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
p.add(playscreen);

}
});
```

Comment: Please describe exactly what you need to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Anonymous new can be replaced with lambda ?**

It's not 100% correct, Anonymous class for an interfaces having one abstract method can be replaced with lambda expression (which is called functional interface)

Since `ActionListener` has only one method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you can write it using lambda expression

```
Play.addActionListener((event) -> {
JPanel playscreen = new JPanel();
playscreen.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
p.add(playscreen);
});
```

**Lambda Expressions**

> One issue with anonymous classes is that if the implementation of your anonymous class is very simple, such as an interface that contains only one method, then the syntax of anonymous classes may seem unwieldy and unclear. In these cases, you're usually trying to pass functionality as an argument to another method, such as what action should be taken when someone clicks a button. Lambda expressions enable you to do this, to treat functionality as method argument, or code as data.

**FunctionalInterface**

> A functional interface has exactly one abstract method. Since default methods have an implementation, they are not abstract. If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of java.lang.Object, that also does not count toward the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from java.lang.Object or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be changed to this:

```
Play.addActionListener((event) -> {
    JPanel playscreen = new JPanel();
    playscreen.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    p.add(playscreen);
});
```

The reason you can do this is because `ActionListener` is a functional interface, meaning that it has exactly one abstract method that you *must* implement. A lambda is able to essentially take the place of that single function and act as an implementation of that interface.

The Lambda acts like the implementation of the method `actionPerformed` and `(event)` is the argument to that method and the `-> { ... }` is the body of that method.